# Compare Only Time part in Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

I want to find if a event exist or not in the mongodb based on title,start date and start time. This is one event stored in mongo db:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55bb834330b16c0bdadc6cd8"),
"event_id" : 26757,
"title" : "Corporate Training using cinema",
"title_slug" : "the-spiritual-companys-corporate-training-using-cinema",
"subtitle" : "",
"description" : "The spiritual company has a session where in it intends to provide corporate training via the medium of cinema.\r\n\r\nHow will they impart this quirk? Well be there to find out mate.\r\n\r\nFees - INR 1500/-",
"location" : ObjectId("55bb834330b16c0bdadc6cd6"),
"start_time" : ISODate("1900-01-01T10:00:00Z"),
"end_time" : ISODate("1900-01-01T01:00:00Z"),
"start_date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T00:00:00Z"),
"end_date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T00:00:00Z"),
"post_date" : ISODate("2015-07-31T15:12:46Z"),
"last_modified" : ISODate("2015-07-31T15:12:46Z"),
"all_day" : false,
"image_url" : "",
"thumbnail_url" : "",
"publish_status" : 4,
"moderation_status" : 4,
"categories" : [
    ObjectId("55bb7d9b30b16c0bdadc5c8c")
],
"tags" : [ ],
"organizer" : ObjectId("55bb834330b16c0bdadc6cd7"),
"editor" : ObjectId("55bb44da30b16c7b1a39157b"),
"repeat_bool" : false,
"group_id" : "26757"
}
```

I get a succesful result by searching for only title and start date but when I include time part I get an empty list.
This is my query in mongoengine in python 2.7+:

```
from mongoengine import *
from model import *
from datetime import date
db = connect('xyz')

#The query starts here
#The model contains the Event document

b = date(2015,8,1).isoformat()
a = Event.objects(title = "Corporate Training using cinema", start_date = b, start_time = "1900-01-01T10:00:00Z")
```

When I execute the above query the result I get is an empty list i.e it did not find the event in db.

```
>>>a
>>>[]
```

If I do not include the start_time in query then it's execution gets me a successful result but I have to include the start_time in query.
How do I compare the start_time in mongoengine or just the time part?

Answer (score 0):

You are matching a string with ISO date object first convert your input to a ISO Date object . I don't know the syntax of Python but in php I use

```
$match=new MongoDate(timestamp)
```

include the above class in your syntax